# Populated Sqlite DB with Phonegap for Android

Tags: android, cordova, android-sqlite, phonegap-plugins

I have been trying to populate SQLite DB with phonegap for Android.I am following this [post](http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2012/7/27/Guest-Blog-Post-Shipping-a-populated-SQLite-DB-with-PhoneGap). I have been able to follow the first two steps i.e using [this plugin](https://github.com/pgsqlite/PG-SQLitePlugin-Android).
My question is:
1) When i was able to populate a database by following 1st step, Why should i follow the second and third steps?
2) Following third step, I ended up in dilemma as i dint find any file named "0000000000000001.db" in data > data > [MY APP NAME] > app_database. And my Database.db is in 
data > data > [MY APP NAME] > databases.

[image]

my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=320; user-scalable=no" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Minimal AppLaud App</title>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.7.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="SQLitePlugin.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
function onDeviceReady() {
var db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "Demo", -1);
db.transaction(function(tx) {
tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test_table');
tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test_table 
(id integer primary key, data    text, data_num integer)');
tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO test_table (data, data_num) VALUES (?,?)", 
["test", 100],    function(tx, res) {
console.log("insertId: " + res.insertId + " -- probably 1"); 
alert("insertId: " + res.insertId + " -- should be valid");
db.transaction(function(tx) {
tx.executeSql("SELECT data_num from test_table;", [], function(tx, res) {
console.log("res.rows.length: " + res.rows.length + " -- should be 1");
alert("res.rows.length: " + res.rows.length + " -- should be 1");
alert("res.rows.item(0).data_num: " + res.rows.item(0).data_num + "should be 100");
});
});
}, function(e) {
console.log("ERROR: " + e.message);
});
});
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="init();" id="stage" class="theme">
<p>Your app goes here.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

MyPhonegapActivity.java

```
package org.mobinius.sqltry1;

import org.apache.cordova.DroidGap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import java.io.*;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MyPhoneGapActivity extends DroidGap {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     
try
{
String pName = this.getClass().getPackage().getName();
this.copy("Database.db","/data/data/"+pName+"/databases/");
//this.copy("0000000000000001.db","/data/data/"+pName+"/app_database/file__0/");       
}
catch (IOException e)
{
e.printStackTrace();
}        
super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
return true;
}

void copy(String file, String folder) throws IOException {
File CheckDirectory;
CheckDirectory = new File(folder);
if (!CheckDirectory.exists())
{ 
CheckDirectory.mkdir();
}

InputStream in = getApplicationContext().getAssets().open(file);
OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(folder+file);

// Transfer bytes from in to out
byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
int len; while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) out.write(buf, 0, len);
in.close(); out.close();   
}
}
```

As you can see in screen shot there is no db file named "0000000000000001.db". Please help me on this.

Comment: I think the `000000000000000000001.db` is not for `android` it is for `ios`.